# Having weird ADO database issues with Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

I'd really appreciate some help with an issue for a school project that I've been having. What do you guys think could be wrong?
I spoke to a friend who said I must make sure that I only have 1 table's active property set to true at any given time. I tried this but it didn't seem to make a difference. Perhaps I didn't do it properly?

This is the code of my procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.btnChangePassUserClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sNewPass,sOldPass:string;
begin
  sOldPass:= InputBox('Password verification','Please enter your current password','');

  if sOldPass = sPassword then
  begin
      sNewPass := inputBox('Password change','Please enter a new Password with at least 1 number and letter','');
      if isPasswordValid(sNewPass) then
        begin
           tblUsers.Active := True;
            tblUsers.Edit;
            tblUsers.Filtered := True;

            tblUsers.Filter := 'UserID = ' +QuotedStr(sPassword);
            tblUsers.First;
            tblUsers['Password'] := sNewPass;

            tblUsers.Post;
            tblUsers.Filtered := False;
            tblUsers.Filter := '';


          if bRememberMe then
            begin
              ShowMessage('Password changed, please log in again for security purposes');
              imgLogoutClick(Sender);
            end;

          sPassword := sNewPass;
        end
      else ShowMessage('Please ensure your password contains at least 1 letter and 1 number');
  end
  else ShowMessage('Incorrect Password');
end;
```

The error I get:

> tblUsers: Dataset not in edit or insert mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `Edit`, `Filter`, and `Filtered` are all incorrect. You need to `Edit` only when actually editing the row; any change in the cursor (record pointer) position will cancel or post changes, taking the table out of edit mode (and thus your error).

You also shouldn't use `Filter` to search for data for editing. Use `Locate` instead. Something like this should work for you (although it's probably not what I would use in my own code):

```
procedure TForm1.btnChangePassUserClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sNewPass,sOldPass:string;
begin
  sOldPass:= InputBox('Password verification','Please enter your current password','');

  if sOldPass = sPassword then
  begin
    sNewPass := inputBox('Password change','Please enter a new Password with at least 1 number and letter','');
    if isPasswordValid(sNewPass) then
    begin
      tblUsers.Active := True;

      // I'd think the search should be on the UserID rather than
      // the password. Are you certain this is what you want to do?
      if tblUsers.Locate('UserID', sPassword, []) then
      begin
        tblUsers.Edit;
        tblUsers['Password'] := sNewPass;
        tblUsers.Post;
      end;
      tblUsers.Active := False;

      if bRememberMe then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Password changed, please log in again for security purposes');
        imgLogoutClick(Sender);
      end;

      sPassword := sNewPass;
    end
    else ShowMessage('Please ensure your password contains at least 1 letter and 1 number');
  end
  else 
    ShowMessage('Incorrect Password');
end;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. My understanding of ADO seemed to be lacking a bit before you posted this but now I understand everything perfectly :). Yeah, I think that when I decided to use the password to filter I had a bit of a brain fart; I did change it but it must have been in a different version of my code. I really appreciate the help, it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

`tblUsers.First` might cause a scroll. I guess the dataset is posted on that scroll.

Try calling `tblUsers.Edit` just before assigning the new password via `tblUsers['Password'] := sNewPass;`.

As MartynA suggests, there is another problem that will prevent your code from working correctly, even when the above is fixed. `tblUsers.Filter := 'UserID = ' +QuotedStr(sPassword);` is most likely not what you want to do. Probably a variable containing `UserID` should be passed rather than `sPassword`.

If I remember correctly, there should be a function called `Locate`. It should be faster than a filter, as well.